# Asteroids Game, Object Oriented Orogramming, Python

Tags: python, arcade

I am making an asteroids game. I have got the ship moving and
asteroids floating as they should.
I want an explosion to occur when an asteroid collides with the ship, but I am lost on how to make it work. Thank you.

[laserBlue01.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cbwF.png)

[meteorGrey_big1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv6vi.png)

[meteorGrey_med1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePgYx.png)

[meteorGrey_small1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewqQl.png)

[playerShip1_orange.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE7lR.png)

```
import arcade
import random
import math
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

# These are Global constants to use throughout the game
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BULLET_RADIUS = 30
BULLET_SPEED = 10
BULLET_LIFE = 60

SHIP_TURN_AMOUNT = 3
SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT = 0.25
SHIP_RADIUS = 30

INITIAL_ROCK_COUNT = 5

BIG_ROCK_SPIN = 1
BIG_ROCK_SPEED = 1.5
BIG_ROCK_RADIUS = 15

MEDIUM_ROCK_SPIN = -2
MEDIUM_ROCK_RADIUS = 5

SMALL_ROCK_SPIN = 5
SMALL_ROCK_RADIUS = 2

"""
    Flying Object
        -Velocity
        -Point
        -Draw
        -Advance
        -Angle

    Asteroid
    Ship
    Bullet

    SmallRock
    BigRock
    LargeRock """


# This class determines a starting point.
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0.00
        self.y = 0.00


# This class determines speed.
class Velocity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dx = 0.00
        self.dy = 0.00


class FlyingObject(ABC):
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.center = Point()
        self.velocity = Velocity()
        self.alive = True
        self.img = img
        self.texture = arcade.load_texture(self.img)
        self.width = self.texture.width
        self.height = self.texture.height
        self.radius = SHIP_RADIUS
        self.angle = 0
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = 1

        """
        Velocity to be looked at later.
        """
        self.velocity.dx = math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.velocity.dy = math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed

    def advance(self):
        self.wrap()
        self.center.y += self.velocity.dy
        self.center.x += self.velocity.dx

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.alive

    def draw(self):
        arcade.draw_texture_rectangle(
            self.center.x,
            self.center.y,
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.texture,
            self.angle,
            255,
        )

    def hit(self):
        self.alive = False
        return self.hit_score

    def wrap(self):
        if self.center.x > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.center.x -= SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.center.x < 0:
            self.center.x += SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.center.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.center.y -= SCREEN_HEIGHT
        if self.center.y < 0:
            self.center.y += SCREEN_HEIGHT


class Ship(FlyingObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/playerShip1_orange.png")
        self.angle = 1
        self.center.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
        self.center.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2
        self.radius = SHIP_RADIUS

    def left(self):
        self.angle += SHIP_TURN_AMOUNT

    def right(self):
        self.angle -= SHIP_TURN_AMOUNT

    def thrust(self):
        self.velocity.dx -= math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT
        self.velocity.dy += math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT

    def rev_Thrust(self):
        self.velocity.dx += math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT
        self.velocity.dy -= math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT


class Bullet(FlyingObject):
    def __init__(self, ship_angle, ship_x, ship_y):
        super().__init__("images/laserBlue01.png")
        self.radius = BULLET_RADIUS
        self.life = BULLET_LIFE
        self.speed = BULLET_SPEED
        self.angle = ship_angle - 90
        self.center.x = ship_x
        self.center.y = ship_y

    def fire(self):
        self.velocity.dx -= math.sin(math.radians(self.angle + 90)) * BULLET_SPEED
        self.velocity.dy += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle + 90)) * BULLET_SPEED

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.life -= 1
        if self.life <= 0:
            self.alive = False


class Asteroid(FlyingObject):
    def __init__(self, img):
        super().__init__(img)
        self.radius = 0.00
        self.hit_score = 1

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.radius = 0.00

    def hit(self):
        self.alive = False
        return self.hit_score


"""
This class represent the small asteroid size.
"""


class SmallRock(Asteroid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/meteorGrey_small1.png")
        self.radius = SMALL_ROCK_RADIUS
        self.speed = BIG_ROCK_SPEED
        self.lives = 1

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.angle += SMALL_ROCK_SPIN

    def break_apart(self, asteroids):
        self.alive = False

    def hit(self):
        """
        Reduces object life as a bullet hits it.
        """

        self.lives -= 1
        if self.lives == 2:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 1:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 0:
            self.alive = False
            self.hit_score = 5
        return self.hit_score


"""
This class represents the medium asteroid size.
"""


class MediumRock(Asteroid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/meteorGrey_med1.png")
        self.radius = MEDIUM_ROCK_RADIUS
        self.speed = BIG_ROCK_SPEED
        self.velocity.dx = math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.velocity.dy = math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.lives = 2

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.angle += MEDIUM_ROCK_SPIN

    def break_apart(self, asteroids):
        small = SmallRock()
        small.center.x = self.center.x
        small.center.y = self.center.y
        small.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy + 1.5
        small.velocity.dx = self.velocity.dx + 1.5

        small2 = SmallRock()
        small2.center.x = self.center.x
        small2.center.y = self.center.y
        small2.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy - 2
        small2.velocity.dx = self.velocity.dx + 1.5

        asteroids.append(small)
        asteroids.append(small2)
        self.alive = False

    def hit(self):
        """
        Reduces object life as a bullet hits it.
        """

        self.lives -= 1
        if self.lives == 2:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 1:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 0:
            self.alive = False
            self.hit_score = 2
        return self.hit_score


class LargeRock(Asteroid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/meteorGrey_big1.png")
        self.radius = BIG_ROCK_RADIUS
        self.center.x = random.randint(1, 50)
        self.center.y = random.randint(1, 150)
        self.direction = random.randint(1, 50)
        self.speed = BIG_ROCK_SPEED
        self.hit_score = 5
        self.lives = 3
        self.velocity.dx = math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.velocity.dy = math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.angle += BIG_ROCK_SPIN

    """
    This breaks the rock into pieces when hit by a bullet.
    """

    def break_apart(self, asteroids):
        med1 = MediumRock()
        med1.center.x = self.center.x
        med1.center.y = self.center.y
        med1.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy + 2

        med2 = MediumRock()
        med2.center.x = self.center.x
        med2.center.y = self.center.y
        med2.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy - 2

        small = SmallRock()
        small.center.x = self.center.x
        small.center.y = self.center.y
        small.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy + 5

        asteroids.append(med1)
        asteroids.append(med2)
        asteroids.append(small)
        self.alive = False

    def hit(self):
        """
        Reduces object life as a bullet hits it.
        """

        self.lives -= 1
        if self.lives == 2:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 1:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 0:
            self.alive = False
            self.hit_score = 10
        return self.hit_score


class Game(arcade.Window):
    """
    This class handles all the game callbacks and interaction
    This class will then call the appropriate functions of
    each of the above classes.
    You are welcome to modify anything in this class.
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        """
        Sets up the initial conditions of the game
        :param width: Screen width
        :param height: Screen height
        """
        super().__init__(width, height)
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.SMOKY_BLACK)

        self.held_keys = set()

        self.asteroids = []

        for i in range(INITIAL_ROCK_COUNT):
            bigAst = LargeRock()
            self.asteroids.append(bigAst)

        # todo: declare anything here you need the game class to track
        self.ship = Ship()
        self.score = 0

        self.bullets = []

    def on_draw(self):
        """
        Called automatically by the arcade framework.
        Handles the responsibility of drawing all elements.
        """

        # clear the screen to begin drawing
        arcade.start_render()

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            asteroid.draw()

        # todo: draw each object
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.draw()

        self.ship.draw()

        self.draw_score()

        """'
        This method removes dead objects from the game and makes the ship
        inactive if it collides with an asteroid
        """

    def draw_score(self):
        """
        Puts the current score on the screen
        """
        score_text = "Score: {}".format(self.score)
        start_x = 10
        start_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 20
        arcade.draw_text(
            score_text,
            start_x=start_x,
            start_y=start_y,
            font_size=12,
            color=arcade.color.NAVY_BLUE,
        )

    def remove_DeadObjects(self):
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            if not bullet.alive:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            if not asteroid.alive:
                self.asteroids.remove(asteroid)
            if not self.ship.alive:

                """
                Opens a Game Over Window when the ship collides with an asteroid
                """
                arcade.open_window(700, 400, "Game Over")
                arcade.start_render()
                arcade.draw_text(
                    text="GAME OVER! TRY AGAIN",
                    start_x=20,
                    start_y=200,
                    color=arcade.color.RED,
                    font_size=50,
                )
                arcade.finish_render()
                arcade.run()

    def check_collisions(self):
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            for asteroid in self.asteroids:
                if bullet.alive and asteroid.alive:
                    distance_x = abs(asteroid.center.x - bullet.center.x)
                    distance_y = abs(asteroid.center.y - bullet.center.y)
                    max_dist = asteroid.radius + bullet.radius
                    if (distance_x < max_dist) and (distance_y < max_dist):
                        asteroid.break_apart(self.asteroids)
                        bullet.alive = False
                        asteroid.alive = False
                        bullet.alive = False

                        # collision to occur
                        print("Collision of asteroid and bullet.")

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            if self.ship.alive and asteroid.alive:
                distance_x = abs(asteroid.center.x - self.ship.center.x)
                distance_y = abs(asteroid.center.y - self.ship.center.y)
                max_dist = asteroid.radius + self.ship.radius
                if (distance_x < max_dist) and (distance_y < max_dist):
                    self.ship.alive = False
                    asteroid.alive = False
                    print("Asteroid collides with ship")

    def update(self, delta_time):
        """
        Update each object in the game.
        :param delta_time: tells us how much time has actually elapsed
        """
        self.check_keys()

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            asteroid.advance()

        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.advance()

        self.remove_DeadObjects()
        self.check_collisions()

        self.ship.advance()

        # TODO: Tell everything to advance or move forward one step in time

        # TODO: Check for collisions

    def check_keys(self):
        """
        This function checks for keys that are being held down.
        You will need to put your own method calls in here.
        """
        if arcade.key.LEFT in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.left()

        if arcade.key.RIGHT in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.right()

        if arcade.key.UP in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.thrust()

        if arcade.key.DOWN in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.rev_Thrust()

        # Machine gun mode...
        # if arcade.key.SPACE in self.held_keys:
        #    pass

    def on_key_press(self, key: int, modifiers: int):
        """
        Puts the current key in the set of keys that are being held.
        ,see;   You will need to add things here to handle firing the bullet.
        """
        if self.ship.alive:
            self.held_keys.add(key)

            if key == arcade.key.SPACE:
                bullet = Bullet(self.ship.angle, self.ship.center.x, self.ship.center.y)
                self.bullets.append(bullet)
                bullet.fire()
                # TODO: Fire the bullet here!

    def on_key_release(self, key: int, modifiers: int):
        """
        Removes the current key from the set of held keys.
        """
        if key in self.held_keys:
            self.held_keys.remove(key)


# Creates the game and starts it going window = Game(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) arcade.run()
```

Comment: Please format your code as "Code sample", not as "blockquote".

Comment: I have formatted it now as a "code sample".

Comment: `I need help with additional features like explosion on collision between an asteroid and the ship, as well as scores working correctly` - please ask one question per post.

Comment: I have asked one question now as required now. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can create the explosion of the ship as a sort of "animation".

I don't know a lot about animation so I suggest you watch these videos to understand a little bit better animations:

Python Arcade library p08 - AnimatedWalkingSprite:https://youtu.be/tM-nKmGi3jA

Python Arcade library p09 - AnimatedTimeSprite: https://youtu.be/Iw51tl4pyNU

For the game over part (which is creating an error on my computer), I suggest you the usage of `View` instead of `Widow`.
Here is an example of the usage of views:
https://arcade.academy/examples/view_instructions_and_game_over.html?highlight=view

If I add the views quickly, that should give us something around this (changes in my code are at lines: 318, 399-403, 497-513):

```
import arcade
import random
import math
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

# These are Global constants to use throughout the game
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

BULLET_RADIUS = 30
BULLET_SPEED = 10
BULLET_LIFE = 60

SHIP_TURN_AMOUNT = 3
SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT = 0.25
SHIP_RADIUS = 30

INITIAL_ROCK_COUNT = 5

BIG_ROCK_SPIN = 1
BIG_ROCK_SPEED = 1.5
BIG_ROCK_RADIUS = 15

MEDIUM_ROCK_SPIN = -2
MEDIUM_ROCK_RADIUS = 5

SMALL_ROCK_SPIN = 5
SMALL_ROCK_RADIUS = 2

"""
    Flying Object
        -Velocity
        -Point
        -Draw
        -Advance
        -Angle

    Asteroid
    Ship
    Bullet

    SmallRock
    BigRock
    LargeRock """


# This class determines a starting point.
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0.00
        self.y = 0.00


# This class determines speed.
class Velocity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dx = 0.00
        self.dy = 0.00


class FlyingObject(ABC):
    def __init__(self, img):
        self.center = Point()
        self.velocity = Velocity()
        self.alive = True
        self.img = img
        self.texture = arcade.load_texture(self.img)
        self.width = self.texture.width
        self.height = self.texture.height
        self.radius = SHIP_RADIUS
        self.angle = 0
        self.speed = 0
        self.direction = 1

        """
        Velocity to be looked at later.
        """
        self.velocity.dx = math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.velocity.dy = math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed

    def advance(self):
        self.wrap()
        self.center.y += self.velocity.dy
        self.center.x += self.velocity.dx

    def is_alive(self):
        return self.alive

    def draw(self):
        arcade.draw_texture_rectangle(
            self.center.x,
            self.center.y,
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.texture,
            self.angle,
            255,
        )

    def hit(self):
        self.alive = False
        return self.hit_score

    def wrap(self):
        if self.center.x > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.center.x -= SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.center.x < 0:
            self.center.x += SCREEN_WIDTH
        if self.center.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.center.y -= SCREEN_HEIGHT
        if self.center.y < 0:
            self.center.y += SCREEN_HEIGHT


class Ship(FlyingObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/playerShip1_orange.png")
        self.angle = 1
        self.center.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
        self.center.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2
        self.radius = SHIP_RADIUS

    def left(self):
        self.angle += SHIP_TURN_AMOUNT

    def right(self):
        self.angle -= SHIP_TURN_AMOUNT

    def thrust(self):
        self.velocity.dx -= math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT
        self.velocity.dy += math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT

    def rev_Thrust(self):
        self.velocity.dx += math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT
        self.velocity.dy -= math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * SHIP_THRUST_AMOUNT


class Bullet(FlyingObject):
    def __init__(self, ship_angle, ship_x, ship_y):
        super().__init__("images/laserBlue01.png")
        self.radius = BULLET_RADIUS
        self.life = BULLET_LIFE
        self.speed = BULLET_SPEED
        self.angle = ship_angle - 90
        self.center.x = ship_x
        self.center.y = ship_y

    def fire(self):
        self.velocity.dx -= math.sin(math.radians(self.angle + 90)) * BULLET_SPEED
        self.velocity.dy += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle + 90)) * BULLET_SPEED

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.life -= 1
        if self.life <= 0:
            self.alive = False


class Asteroid(FlyingObject):
    def __init__(self, img):
        super().__init__(img)
        self.radius = 0.00
        self.hit_score = 1

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.radius = 0.00

    def hit(self):
        self.alive = False
        return self.hit_score


"""
This class represent the small asteroid size.
"""


class SmallRock(Asteroid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/meteorGrey_small1.png")
        self.radius = SMALL_ROCK_RADIUS
        self.speed = BIG_ROCK_SPEED
        self.lives = 1

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.angle += SMALL_ROCK_SPIN

    def break_apart(self, asteroids):
        self.alive = False

    def hit(self):
        """
        Reduces object life as a bullet hits it.
        """

        self.lives -= 1
        if self.lives == 2:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 1:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 0:
            self.alive = False
            self.hit_score = 5
        return self.hit_score


"""
This class represents the medium asteroid size.
"""


class MediumRock(Asteroid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/meteorGrey_med1.png")
        self.radius = MEDIUM_ROCK_RADIUS
        self.speed = BIG_ROCK_SPEED
        self.velocity.dx = math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.velocity.dy = math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.lives = 2

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.angle += MEDIUM_ROCK_SPIN

    def break_apart(self, asteroids):
        small = SmallRock()
        small.center.x = self.center.x
        small.center.y = self.center.y
        small.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy + 1.5
        small.velocity.dx = self.velocity.dx + 1.5

        small2 = SmallRock()
        small2.center.x = self.center.x
        small2.center.y = self.center.y
        small2.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy - 2
        small2.velocity.dx = self.velocity.dx + 1.5

        asteroids.append(small)
        asteroids.append(small2)
        self.alive = False

    def hit(self):
        """
        Reduces object life as a bullet hits it.
        """

        self.lives -= 1
        if self.lives == 2:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 1:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 0:
            self.alive = False
            self.hit_score = 2
        return self.hit_score


class LargeRock(Asteroid):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("images/meteorGrey_big1.png")
        self.radius = BIG_ROCK_RADIUS
        self.center.x = random.randint(1, 50)
        self.center.y = random.randint(1, 150)
        self.direction = random.randint(1, 50)
        self.speed = BIG_ROCK_SPEED
        self.hit_score = 5
        self.lives = 3
        self.velocity.dx = math.cos(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed
        self.velocity.dy = math.sin(math.radians(self.direction)) * self.speed

    def advance(self):
        super().advance()
        self.angle += BIG_ROCK_SPIN

    """
    This breaks the rock into pieces when hit by a bullet.
    """

    def break_apart(self, asteroids):
        med1 = MediumRock()
        med1.center.x = self.center.x
        med1.center.y = self.center.y
        med1.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy + 2

        med2 = MediumRock()
        med2.center.x = self.center.x
        med2.center.y = self.center.y
        med2.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy - 2

        small = SmallRock()
        small.center.x = self.center.x
        small.center.y = self.center.y
        small.velocity.dy = self.velocity.dy + 5

        asteroids.append(med1)
        asteroids.append(med2)
        asteroids.append(small)
        self.alive = False

    def hit(self):
        """
        Reduces object life as a bullet hits it.
        """

        self.lives -= 1
        if self.lives == 2:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 1:
            self.hit_score = 1
        elif self.lives == 0:
            self.alive = False
            self.hit_score = 10
        return self.hit_score


class GameView(arcade.View):
    """
    This class handles all the game callbacks and interaction
    This class will then call the appropriate functions of
    each of the above classes.
    You are welcome to modify anything in this class.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Sets up the initial conditions of the game
        :param width: Screen width
        :param height: Screen height
        """
        super().__init__()
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.SMOKY_BLACK)

        self.held_keys = set()

        self.asteroids = []

        for i in range(INITIAL_ROCK_COUNT):
            bigAst = LargeRock()
            self.asteroids.append(bigAst)

        # todo: declare anything here you need the game class to track
        self.ship = Ship()
        self.score = 0

        self.bullets = []

    def on_draw(self):
        """
        Called automatically by the arcade framework.
        Handles the responsibility of drawing all elements.
        """

        # clear the screen to begin drawing
        arcade.start_render()

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            asteroid.draw()

        # todo: draw each object
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.draw()

        self.ship.draw()

        self.draw_score()

        """'
        This method removes dead objects from the game and makes the ship
        inactive if it collides with an asteroid
        """

    def draw_score(self):
        """
        Puts the current score on the screen
        """
        score_text = "Score: {}".format(self.score)
        start_x = 10
        start_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 20
        arcade.draw_text(
            score_text,
            start_x=start_x,
            start_y=start_y,
            font_size=12,
            color=arcade.color.NAVY_BLUE,
        )

    def remove_DeadObjects(self):
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            if not bullet.alive:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            if not asteroid.alive:
                self.asteroids.remove(asteroid)
            if not self.ship.alive:

                """
                Changes to the game over View
                """
                game_over_view = GameOverView()
                self.window.show_view(game_over_view)


    def check_collisions(self):
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            for asteroid in self.asteroids:
                if bullet.alive and asteroid.alive:
                    distance_x = abs(asteroid.center.x - bullet.center.x)
                    distance_y = abs(asteroid.center.y - bullet.center.y)
                    max_dist = asteroid.radius + bullet.radius
                    if (distance_x < max_dist) and (distance_y < max_dist):
                        asteroid.break_apart(self.asteroids)
                        bullet.alive = False
                        asteroid.alive = False
                        bullet.alive = False

                        # collision to occur
                        print("Collision of asteroid and bullet.")

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            if self.ship.alive and asteroid.alive:
                distance_x = abs(asteroid.center.x - self.ship.center.x)
                distance_y = abs(asteroid.center.y - self.ship.center.y)
                max_dist = asteroid.radius + self.ship.radius
                if (distance_x < max_dist) and (distance_y < max_dist):
                    self.ship.alive = False
                    asteroid.alive = False
                    print("Asteroid collides with ship")

    def update(self, delta_time):
        """
        Update each object in the game.
        :param delta_time: tells us how much time has actually elapsed
        """
        self.check_keys()

        for asteroid in self.asteroids:
            asteroid.advance()

        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.advance()

        self.remove_DeadObjects()
        self.check_collisions()

        self.ship.advance()

        # TODO: Tell everything to advance or move forward one step in time

        # TODO: Check for collisions

    def check_keys(self):
        """
        This function checks for keys that are being held down.
        You will need to put your own method calls in here.
        """
        if arcade.key.LEFT in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.left()

        if arcade.key.RIGHT in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.right()

        if arcade.key.UP in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.thrust()

        if arcade.key.DOWN in self.held_keys:
            self.ship.rev_Thrust()

        # Machine gun mode...
        # if arcade.key.SPACE in self.held_keys:
        #    pass

    def on_key_press(self, key: int, modifiers: int):
        """
        Puts the current key in the set of keys that are being held.
        ,see;   You will need to add things here to handle firing the bullet.
        """
        if self.ship.alive:
            self.held_keys.add(key)

            if key == arcade.key.SPACE:
                bullet = Bullet(self.ship.angle, self.ship.center.x, self.ship.center.y)
                self.bullets.append(bullet)
                bullet.fire()
                # TODO: Fire the bullet here!

    def on_key_release(self, key: int, modifiers: int):
        """
        Removes the current key from the set of held keys.
        """
        if key in self.held_keys:
            self.held_keys.remove(key)


class GameOverView(arcade.View):
    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text(
            text="GAME OVER! TRY AGAIN",
            start_x=20,
            start_y=200,
            color=arcade.color.RED,
            font_size=50,
        )

def main():
    window = arcade.Window(800, 600, "astroid")
    game_view = GameView()
    window.show_view(game_view)
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

# Creates the game and starts it going window = Game(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) arcade.run()
```